# Google App Engine - Searching for Locations within a Specified Distance returning Zero results

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-api, gae-search

Searching geolocations by distance using GAE Search API (1.7.6) returns zero results always...

I build the following query: `distance(geoLocation, geopoint(27.241131, -82.464445)) < 16093 /*  10 Miles in meters */`

Results are always zero although I have geopoints within the distance. For instance my search origin is in this case `lat: 27.241131, lgn: -82.464445` and one of the geopoints within the range is `lat:27.233247, lng-82.48819800000001.`

When I calculate the distance using google maps api v3 like this:

```
  google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (
new google.maps.LatLng(27.241131, -82.464445), 
new google.maps.LatLng(27.233247, -82.48819800000001)) = 2509.46
```

This is how I store geopoints along with other fields

```
dictFields = []

dictFields.append(search.AtomField(name = 'zipcode', value = k.get('zipcode')))

geopoint = search.GeoPoint(float(lat), float(lng))
dictFields.append(search.GeoField(name = 'geoLocation', value = geopoint))
```

Later I do

```
search.Document(doc_id = document_id, fields = dictFields)
```

What is wrong here? I know that Search works because it returns results when I search by other fields different than geopoints.

Search id done like this:

```
options = search.QueryOptions(limit=1000, returned_fields=['geoLocation', 'zipcode'])
query = search.Query(query_string=query_str, options=options)
```

where `query_str = distance(geoLocation, geopoint(27.241131, -82.464445)) < 16093`

Update

I'm testing using the geopoint stored by the index and get search.SearchResults(number_found=0L). 
Question: Is this suppose to work in the dev environment?

Help is appreciated!!!!!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an open issue on this too - I did some prying and it looks like a problem with the development environment. It works in the production environment.

See issue if you want to follow:
[Why is geosearching/location based searches returning zero results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616200/why-is-geosearching-location-based-searches-returning-zero-results)

You'll also find a link to an issue tracker I posed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If you say you tested it and works in prod that's what I need to know and I will go with your answer.
Also I noticed that when you do a search (just because you are testing your logic) and have no documents indexed a weird exception gets thrown, something related to a matched_count = 0. Then if you go to the SDK console and click the Fulltext index tab it will brake with a nasty exception.

Comment: odd behavior indeed. let me know if you see different in the production environment. Odd behavior indeed. A little discouraged by the lack of testing as these are some pretty obvious bugs. To get to your full text search in the dev environment, you can just paste localhost:admin_port#/search/index?index=YOUR INDEX NAME HERE&query=&namespace=     That's a workaround I guess until that link landing page is fixed.

Comment: Glad it works in prod. The only weird thing I've noticed is that I'm getting more results that I expect. So I want to find some locations within 5 'miles'.. so I convert 5 miles to meters and I have 8047m. And when I look at the result.. I don't know.. you can tell that there is no way that many of the returned markers are within 5 miles from the center point... you know what I mean? Am I doing something wrong with the conversion?

Comment: That's interesting - you're conversion looks okay... try debugging by logging the distances of each result and play around with the range - start at 1 mile and go up from there. I haven't seen that in my results, but let me know how things look when you debug. Make sure the center point is the actual center point being used in the query

Comment: Thanks @kevin. I checked all that and seems like I'm doing the right thing. I decided to go with 5000 = 5 miles. Thanks a lot.